# I am cloning git hub repository to Cpanel git version control i am getting term 15 error

Tags: git, github, cpanel

I am cloning git hub repository to Cpanel git version control i am getiing the error below,

Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” ended prematurely because it received the “TERM” (15) signal:

i have added my ssh key to git hub deploy keys, what is this Term 15, referring to even folder have write permissions too.

[image]